# Progressive Matrix question - shapes with shaded and unshaded parts

Tags: pattern, visual, progressive-matrix

[image]

This question is from a Korean book called IQ festival Practical Mensa IQ test and the book does not have answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the answer is

> D

the reason

> Different from GileBrt's answer, Imagine each column representing 3 three-dimensional jars
>  The first row will give a point of view if we look from above (from the mouth of the jar), the dark part is the inside of the jars
>  The second row will give a point of view if we look from the side
>  The third row, I think it should give a point of view if we look from the bottom, so the answer is D

Comment: Great observation!

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is

> D

Explanation:

> The third row reflects the area colored in the first row.